# Passing an object while creating dynamic HTML is throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am creating HTML of bootstrap Modal at run time and binding it to body as shown below.

**Modal Html**

```
function GetConfirmationModalHtml(HeaderMessage, Message,YesEvent, Noevent) {
        var html = '<div id="clearModal"><div class="modal fade confirmation-modal" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" style="display:block; opacity:1;">'
+ '<div class="modal-dialog vertcial-center modal-sm">'
+ '<div class="modal-content">'
+ '<div class="modal-header">'

  + '<h4 class="modal-title">' + HeaderMessage + '</h4>'
+ '</div>'
+ '<div class="modal-body">'
  + '<p>' + Message + '</p>'
+ '</div>'
+ '<div class="modal-footer">'
+ '          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-confirmation-yes" ng-click="' + YesEvent + '" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>'
+ '          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-confirmation-no" ng-click="' + Noevent + '" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>'
+ '      </div>'
+ '  </div>'
+ '</div>'
+ '</div></div>';

        return html;
    }
```

Modal has two buttons one is *Yes* and second is *No*. While calling function for getting HTML I am sending events of both buttons as parameters and when I get HTML I bind it using `$compile` to the body. It works fine when I don't send any object as a events parameters. But when object is sent like
**ticket.toString()**
 it throws following error

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 49 of the expression [PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket([object Object])] starting at [Object])].
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/syntax?p0=Object&p1=is%20unexpecte…ing%20%5B%5D%5D&p2=49&p3=PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket(%5Bobjectbject%5D)&p4=Object%5D)

Btu when I pass objects as
**JSON.stringify(ticket)** it throws below error.

> Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: 
>   PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket({
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/ueoe?p0=PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket(%7B
>
> ```
> at http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:68:12
> at AST.peekToken (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14574:13)
> at AST.object (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14515:14)
> at AST.primary (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14433:22)
> at AST.unary (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14421:19)
> at AST.multiplicative (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14408:21)
> at AST.additive (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14399:21)
> at AST.relational (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14390:21)
> at AST.equality (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14381:21)
> at AST.logicalAND (http://localhost:2053/Scripts/js/angular.js:14373:21) <button
> ```
>
> type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-confirmation-yes"
>   ng-click="PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket({"
>   ticketid":25,"eventid":122,"ticketname":"qwe","quantityavailable":213,"tickettypeid":"2","amountperticket":1,"totalamount":213,"eventdescription":"23","startdatetime":"=""
>   date(1486456200000)="" ","enddatetime":"="" date(1486470600000)=""
>   ","utcstartdatetime":"="" date(1486427400000)=""
>   ","utcenddatetime":"="" date(1486441800000)=""
>   ","startdate":"february="" 07="" 2017","starttime":"02:00=""
>   pm","enddate":"february="" 2017","endtime":"06:00=""
>   pm","minimumticketallowedperorder":1,"maximumticketallowedperorder":10,"isactive":true,"tickettype":"paid","grandtotal":1213,"$$hashkey":"object:326","copyobject":{"ticketid":25,"eventid":122,"ticketname":"qwe","quantityavailable":213,"tickettypeid":"2","amountperticket":1,"totalamount":213,"eventdescription":"23","startdatetime":"=""
>   pm","minimumticketallowedperorder":1,"maximumticketallowedperorder":10,"isactive":true,"tickettype":"paid","grandtotal":1213},"iseditmode":true})"=""
>   data-dismiss="modal">

Below is whole code.

**Function calling above function for Modal HTML**

```
CancelEditTicketConfirmation: function (ticket) {
            var html = GetConfirmationModalHtml('Confirmation', 'Some ticket(s) are in edit mode. Do you want to continue without saving their records ?', "PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket(" + JSON.stringify(ticket) + ")", "NoEvent()");
            $('body').append($compile(html)($scope));
            alignModal();
        },
```

**Event which will be called when User will click On Yes**

```
CancelEditTicket: function (ticket) {
            ticket.TicketName = ticket.copyObject.TicketName;
            ticket.QuantityAvailable = ticket.copyObject.QuantityAvailable;
            ticket.TicketTypeId = ticket.copyObject.TicketTypeId;
            ticket.AmountPerTicket = ticket.copyObject.AmountPerTicket;
            $('#clearModal').remove();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The string above is not a valid string as you can't have unescaped double quotes inside a double quote-wrapped string.

Try the following.

```
var html = GetConfirmationModalHtml('Confirmation', 'Some ticket(s) are in edit mode. Do you want to continue without saving their records ?', "PlanEventTicket.Events.CancelEditTicket('" + JSON.stringify(ticket) + "')", "NoEvent()");
```